# What the error in this code, the server will upload photos but not text files?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my form action file in php.

I am successful in uploading images but text files are producing 'Invalid File Error'.

What may be the error and how to resolve it?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0;
    $target_path = "wep/";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));
        $file_extension = end($ext);
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];
        $j = $j + 1;
        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
                echo $j . ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {
                echo $j . ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {
            echo $j . ').<span id="error">Invalid file Size or Type</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this?? Show proper code

Comment: can you post the whole code so that we can check it....

Comment: Code should be self-explanatory. You do not need to use that many comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have the following line:

```
$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
```

As text files are not included in these valid extensions, your code is telling you what is wrong, "Invalid file Size or Type".  Add text file extensions to the valid extensions array, and they should upload without error.

Answer (score 0):

by adding the allowed extensions to `.txt` then only you can  upload text file. I have added some extensions on the code mentioned by you, you can further add the extensions on this

```
 <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $j = 0;     
        $target_path = "wep/";     
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png","pdf","txt","zip","pptx","doc"); // add your extensions here      
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));  
        $file_extension = end($ext);  
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     
        $j = $j + 1;       
        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)     
        && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {

        echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else {    
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
        } else {     
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">Invalid file Size or Type</span><br/><br/>';
        }
        }
        }
        ?>
```